Start Script with SSH Session Name and Date Time
I am a network engineer, and I am trying to transition off of using programs like securecrt into fully linux based. However, the biggest thing keeping me from migrating is logging SSH output into files.
The goal is to log all items I do on network equipment via the CLI. Specifically if I am troubleshooting or making changes. I can go back to confirm what I did or what I saw.
I would prefer not having to start up logging when I ssh into the device and I was hoping I could use the SSH config to do this. Specifically I was considering using "Script" to do the logging to a file.
I was also looking at the OpenSSH LocalCommand flag to pass the output to some local command. But I don't think that would work either.
I was considering creating a new function within bash. But I don't want to have to change what command I use for SSH based on hosts. I want the sshconfig to utilize the localcommand for the hosts I define.
The other requirement is that I would love to format the logfile with <hostname/ip>-<date>_<month>_<year>.log. That would help me keep everything organized fairly well.
Has anyone done this?
Thanks.

Our IT team use wallix (paid solution) for auditing what's done through SSH/HTTPS connections to critical hardware. For a free solution there are some possibilities when the target is a Linux/UNIX; for eg. terminal multiplexers have logging options; there's also script which can "replay" what's been done. I don't use them frequently so I don't know their actual limitations and their adaptability to your purposes

See the answers to https://askubuntu.com/questions/80371/bash-history-handling-with-multiple-terminals/

Proably best to enable logging in your terminal emulator. See info -n Log screen or the tmux equivalent (screen and tmux being terminal emulators that sit in another terminal emulator adding many extra features including multiplexing, detaching, logging, searching, splitting...)

sudo has options for nice login (along with timestamp and all). You can configure to allow sudo -u $user ssh XXX with out (sudo)password, but some login. (posted as a comment, as I provide no technical detail)

As mentioned in the comments there are multiple ways to accomplish the logging of an SSH session.
Here's a few avenues to explore:

Logging into ssh with: ssh user@host "script -T -B session-name-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log"
This will login and immediately start the script and save it in a log file in the home directory of your user on that file. It saves both input and output in the same file.

Use TMUX or Screen, as long as you have the server running you will have access to the history. You can also save TMUX pane buffers to a file, you will need to configure the max scrollback. I recommend always using a terminal multiplexer, but #1 is a better option.

Use an orchestration platform like Jenkins or Rundeck. This is probably the most complicated solution, however if this is for a professional environment it's probably the best solution. This will essentially allow you to take the input section of the script files generated in solution #1 and re-run the commands automatically. These orchestration platforms log terminal output to a database and you can backup the database as well.



Note that the OP is ssh'ing to network equipment (switches, firewalls...), not Unix servers, where they'll get a specific CLI environment, not a Unix shell where you can run script/screen/tmux, so those will have to be run locally.

Your suggestion for script may be perfectly acceptable. Wrap the ssh command up with it and create a timestamp-based log file
script -c 'ssh user@rhost' "session.$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M).log"

You could create a replacement for ssh. Let's call this file sssh; make it executable and ensure it's somewhere in your $PATH:
#!/bin/bash
#
# Usage: sssh [<…ssh options…>] [<user>@]<host>
########################################################################
#
options=("$@")
userhost=${options[-1]}
host=${userhost##*@}

exec script -c "ssh ${options[*]}" "session.$host.$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M).$$.log"

It will choke if any of your ssh options contains whitespace or characters special to the shell. It requires that the [user]@host part is the last argument (so you can't, for example, use ssh user@host some command…), but for connections to network devices I have assumed it's unlikely you'll be able to execute commands remotely like this anyway.
